# OOO javascript: object self reference returns undefined but console shows it exists

Tags: javascript, oop, object, reference

Okay, so I did search a bit before posting... no luck (or maybe I'm just stupid).

I have this array I call "myArray" and I push objects onto it to populate some variables:

```
myArray.push({
    time        : (y.moveTime - y.startTime),
    pos         : y.move,
    last        : myArray[y.recents.length-1].time
});
```

My issue is why does firebug complain about the "last" variable: "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined*". If I do

```
last        : myArray[y.recents.length-1]
```

everything is fine.

An observation I don't understand:
The array is empty when I have the ".time" reference, but if I remove it, the array is full.

**What am I missing here?** I don't get it :(

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I should add that i do understand that the very first item in this array will have the "last" variable "undefined" since it's got nothing to refer back to.

Comment: Have you checked that `myArray[y.recents.length - 1]` exists and is not `undefined`?

Comment: @tim You have the answer right there in your own comment: For the first item `myArray[y.recents.length-1]` is undefined, and `undefined.time` fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that the evaluated value of

```
myArray[y.recents.length-1]
```

is not an object that has a `time` property. This likely occurs when you perform the first `push` because the array does not yet have any elements.

If you want to hide the error and just assign the `last` property to `undefined` in this case, you can just add a fallback value:

```
last: (myArray[y.recents.length - 1] || {}).time
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `myArray[y.recents.length-1]` can be anything (some string, object, array, null etc.). you can set the value of `last` with it and will not make any error.

however, if you set a property to a non-object (like setting `time`), it will cause an error.